# How to make sure DockerVersion is available for docker inspect

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-build, docker-cli

I am building docker images in another docker container (dind container). I see that the newly built docker image does not have the "DockerVersion" attached. I want to ensure that this information is available for any further builds. How can this be achieved?

The output for docker inspect for my image:

```
$ docker inspect <image-id> | grep DockerVer
    "DockerVersion": "",
```

Comment: What version of Docker is being used to build the images?

Comment: The latest I tried with was 20.10.10